# Apple Quicktime skips during video playback

Tags: windows-xp, video, quicktime, playback

I'm on Windows XP SP3, and I'm running Apple Quicktime v7.6.5.

When viewing MPEG-4 videos, every 30 seconds or so, the playback will halt for 5 seconds, and then resume at a point 10 seconds or so into the future.

In essence, it is freezing and skipping.

Any ideas how to combat this?

My laptop is an NEC Versa, with graphics supplied by a mobile Intel 915gm/gms,910gml express chipset family.

Comment: Do you have any other app accessing the hdd while playing? Does this happen for all video resolutions?

Comment: There is no other app accessing the HDD.  It does happen for all video resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

Download [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) and trying playing it with that.

If the same issues persist, it is most likely either an issue with your OS/Drivers/Laptop or with the videos themselves.